# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool with 'primary' found.) when rendering results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm working on an API on rails 6.0. Some models in the app connects to a 2nd database, and here's the setup in database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 50 } %>

test:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: tr_util_test
  trmain:
    <<: *default
    database: tr_test
    migrations_paths: db/trmain_migrate

development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: tr_util_dev
  trmain:
    <<: *default
    database: tr_dev
    migrations_paths: db/trmain_migrate
```

And the model:

```
class Appuser < TrBase
  ...
end

class TrBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  connects_to database: { writing: :trmain, reading: :trmain }
end
```

And the controller:

```
def show
  appuser_id = params[:id]
  user_details = Appuser.find_user_details(appuser_id: appuser_id)
  render json: user_details, status: 200
end
```

In testing, the find_user_details method ran without any issue and user_details was set to the expected results. However, an "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool with 'primary' found.)" error was thrown in render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding "each_serializer: nil" to render. It seems like Rails doesn't have a connection pool to 'primary' because this end point just connects to the :trmain db, but render for some reason wants to find a ActiveRecord serializer from primary.

```
def show
  appuser_id = params[:id]
  user_details = Appuser.find_user_details(appuser_id: appuser_id)
  render json: user_details, status: 200, each_serializer: nil
end
```